# Is there any way to extend exsiting viewmodel in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have such code:

```
function ModelA() {
    var self = this;

    self.Message = ko.observable("Mesage");
}

ko.applyBindings(new ModelA());
```

and I want to somehow inherit already binded model by another model:

```
function Modelb() {
    var self = this;

    self.Message2 = ko.observable("Mesage2");
}
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as an alternative to damiens answer, if the model you are trying to extend your original model to is dynamic, you are probably best off creating an observale inside the original model.

```
function ModelA() {
    var self = this;

    self.Message = ko.observable("Message");
    self.SubModel = ko.observable();

    self.extendModelB = function() {
        self.SubModel(new ModelB());
    }

    self.extendModelC = function() {
        self.SubModel(new ModelC());
    }
}

function ModelB() {
    var self = this;

    self.Message2 = ko.observable("Message2");
}

function ModelC() {
    var self = this;

    self.Message3 = ko.observable("Message3");
}
```

and then use the `with` binding on SubModel observable.  just another option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need to extend model that was already binded? and you didn't answer to this question.

Comment: Without calling apply bindings multiple times (which you shouldn't be doing for a single model/view anyway), you are unable to dynamically create new properties on your view model and expect them to be bound to your view.  What I've described is one option, [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html) is another alternative that you can follow that may better suite your needs.

Comment: It doesn't solves my problems, but thanks for answering. Nice nickname:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plunk that might help: http://plnkr.co/edit/M1Pt9Lt4UKB0Coe3PauH

If an Html element is bound to the model, the property, or function, the element is bound to needs to be part of the model at the time it is bound.

This might help too: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html